# How to Place custom view in IOS over another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-action

I want to achieve following custom view over `UIViewController` . What is the best way to acheive it rather then using addSubview I want to use some thing better.
I previously use following but i want to use some thing better now

```
[self.view addSubview:NotConnected.view];

 [self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

[image]

I have implemented code using https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview.

I didn't prefer to use library so how is it possible to customise `UIViewController` over another `UIViewController` as shown in image above. I use

```
- (IBAction)ContinueToPayment:(id)sender {

    PayByVC *Newpage = [[PayByVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"PayByVC" bundle:nil];
    Newpage.checkOutInfoDict=checkOutDict;
    Newpage.modalPresentationStyle   = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
    Newpage.modalTransitionStyle     = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    Newpage.view.backgroundColor     = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.4];
    Newpage.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:Newpage animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

To remove from super view I have used

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

How can I place the payby view in centre of screen in all type of screen orientation

Comment: There are many custom libs available for custom alerts: 1. [Popup](https://github.com/miscavage/Popup) 2. [DoAlerView](https://github.com/donobono/DoAlertView) 3. [KLCPopup](https://github.com/jmascia/KLCPopup) 4. [MKBoxInputView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mkinputboxview) Hope these help you out.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Modal presentation with `OverFullScreen` mode. Set the background of the ViewController's view to transparent and place your custom view in the center of it.

Easiest would be to use storyboards. Create a view controller with your custom view in the center. Otherwise, you need to call `view.addSubView(..)` to place your custom view on the center and create the constraints accordingly. 
To present this view controller you can create a segue or by code `presentViewController(...)`. Don't forget to set the `modalPresentationStyle` to `OverFullScreen`.

No library required.

Comment: what can i use to place over the view either addsubview or presentview or else

Comment: Updated the answer with more details. Basically - use storyboards! It will save you a lot of trouble

Comment: I have done the as shown in above and code is modified

Comment: Yes now i want to access to first view function how do u think is the best way

Comment: That is a different question than what you originally asked. You need to use Auto Layout when you build your view to support multiple screen sizes. I would suggest posting another question, you can post a link to it here so we can help you. Also don't forget to mark an the correct answer to close this thread

Comment: i am unable to post any other questions since i have multiple zero vote questions so can u help me out to lift me out by voting the questions

Comment: a tip - mark the correct answer to receive points. then go and try to help other people to up your score

Comment: This is a smart solution

Answer (score 1):

AddSubview for UIAlertView is not possible from iOS 7.

The only way is to create a custom UIView subclass which can act as UIAlertView.

The linked one https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview seems to work well. By putting proper version check one can identify to go for native UIAlertView or CustomAlertView.

Comment: Ok i will try to check them

Comment: I find it useful thaks for your help

Comment: can u check my recent modified questions

Comment: Yes it is possible to use nib file for design purpose.

Comment: Can you give me some ideas how to achieve it

Comment: Are you using storyboard to designs your controller?

Comment: Here is an example using swift : http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6

and using XIBs : http://sebastiancelis.com/2014/06/12/using-xibs-layout-custom-views/

Comment: I am using nib and objective c

Comment: Do u have any idea how to implement it rather then using alert view and library. can you check out the modified questions

Comment: I m unable to post questions coz of negative marking can u help me out to remove negative marking

Answer (score 1):

Try [CRToast](https://github.com/cruffenach/CRToast) I have been using it in my project. Create a util class do the config there.

```
+(NSDictionary *)setupAlertWithMessage:(NSString *) message withError:(BOOL) error{
    NSDictionary *options;

    if(error){

        options = @{
                    kCRToastTextKey : message,
                    kCRToastNotificationTypeKey:@(CRToastPresentationTypePush),
                    kCRToastNotificationPresentationTypeKey:@(CRToastPresentationTypePush),
                    kCRToastTextAlignmentKey : @(NSTextAlignmentCenter),
                    kCRToastBackgroundColorKey : [UIColor colorWithRed:234/255.0 green:85/255.0 blue:72/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                    kCRToastAnimationInTypeKey : @(CRToastAnimationTypeSpring),
                    kCRToastAnimationOutTypeKey : @(CRToastAnimationTypeSpring),
                    kCRToastAnimationInDirectionKey : @(CRToastAnimationDirectionTop),
                    kCRToastAnimationOutDirectionKey : @(CRToastAnimationDirectionBottom)
                    };


    }else{
        options = @{
                    kCRToastTextKey : message,
                    kCRToastNotificationTypeKey:@(CRToastPresentationTypePush),
                    kCRToastNotificationPresentationTypeKey:@(CRToastPresentationTypePush),
                    kCRToastTextAlignmentKey : @(NSTextAlignmentCenter),
                    kCRToastBackgroundColorKey :[UIColor colorWithRed:65/255.0 green:165/255.0 blue:151/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                    kCRToastAnimationInTypeKey : @(CRToastAnimationTypeSpring),
                    kCRToastAnimationOutTypeKey : @(CRToastAnimationTypeSpring),
                    kCRToastAnimationInDirectionKey : @(CRToastAnimationDirectionTop),
                    kCRToastAnimationOutDirectionKey : @(CRToastAnimationDirectionBottom)
                    };

    }

    return options;

   }
```

Then import your util class where ever you need to then use it this way:

```
[CRToastManager showNotificationWithOptions:[MyRateUtil setupAlertWithMessage:@"Alert!" withError:YES/NO]
                                    completionBlock:^{

                                    }];
```

Comment: Do u have any idea how to implement it rather then using alert view and library. can you check out the modified questions

Comment: Yes now i want to access to first view function how do u think is the best way

Comment: I get your question now. I first thought you just needed a mechanism to show alert message.  i once needed to create a dialog like you have shown. use a regular view controller and perform a modal segue to it.

Comment: Ok dude do u have answer for the questions and can u help me to increase upvote for my question i m unable to post any other questions

Comment: I m unable to post questions coz of negative marking can u help me out to remove negative marking