# Two text field in alert view, with space between them

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have a UIAlertView with text fields. Can somebody help me with how I should do to have some space between them ?

```
newBoatAlert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;

UITextField * alertTextField1 = [newBoatAlert textFieldAtIndex:0];
alertTextField1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
alertTextField1.placeholder = @"Name";

UITextField * alertTextField2 = [newBoatAlert textFieldAtIndex:1];
alertTextField2.frame=CGRectMake(alertTextField1.frame.origin.x, alertTextField1.frame.origin.y+alertTextField1.frame.size.height+10, alertTextField1.frame.size.width, alertTextField1.frame.size.height+40);

alertTextField2.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
alertTextField2.placeholder = @"Description";
alertTextField2.secureTextEntry=NO;
```

Now it looks like this :

[image]

Comment: You will need to create your custom control for this.

Comment: You shouldn`t use UIAlertView anymore, it is deprecated in iOS 8. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit the built-in `UIAlertView` styles that Apple provides (at least not without dirty hacks that will probably be broken by the next iOS release).

If you want to customise how the alert looks, for example adding space between text fields, you should create your own `UIView` subclass and implement your own alert UI from scratch.

Also, if you do choose to use Apple's built in alert instead of rolling your own, `UIAlertView` is now deprecated, and you should be using [`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertController) instead. It provides the same features for textboxes, plus more customisation options for buttons (you still can't change the layout though).

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom `UIviewcontroller` so you caan acheive eveerythings as you wished. My this post might be useful to you . You can check it out

[How to Place custom view in IOS over another view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069028/how-to-place-custom-view-in-ios-over-another-view)