# Custom UIView like UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8.1

Would like to learn how `UIPopoverController` style `UIView`s are created.Below is the image from Storehouse iOS app running on iPhone(apple design award winner) , you can see the view moreover looks like `UIPopoverController` ,any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Look at the question I've mentioned iPhone(UIPopoverController is strictly for iPad).All I want to ask is UIPopover like view on iPhone.

Comment: in iPhone UIPopoverController will not work. you have to use custom view or custom library like https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover/.

Comment: You can handle your own custom view  check out this [Place custom view in IOS over another view][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069028/how-to-place-custom-view-in-ios-over-another-view

Answer (score 1):

You can handle your own custom view check out this  [How to Place custom view in IOS over another view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069028/how-to-place-custom-view-in-ios-over-another-view)

You can use this

```
- (IBAction)ContinueToPayment:(id)sender {

    PayByVC *Newpage = [[PayByVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"PayByVC" bundle:nil];
    Newpage.checkOutInfoDict=checkOutDict;
    Newpage.modalPresentationStyle   = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
    Newpage.modalTransitionStyle     = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    Newpage.view.backgroundColor     = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.4];
    Newpage.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:Newpage animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```